# need to call onDataReturnInitializeTable in custom callback

Tags: javascript, yui

I need to call onDataReturnInitializeTable yui datatable method from custom call back function.
Normally I would use on success of sendRequest method like this:

```
success: onDataReturnInitializeTable,
```

but now I need to do something else after that. I tried to do this

```
success: function(e) {
dataTable.onDataReturnInitializeTable;
//do my code here
},
```

but that won't work cause onDataReturnInitializeTable is a function and needs to be called in correct context

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

```
success: function(e) {
    dataTable.onDataReturnInitializeTable.apply(this, arguments);
    //do my code here
},
```

This is a generic JavaScript trick, it is not limited to DataTable.